# Designing Simple Push Notifications System

Tags: postgresql, symfony, push-notification

Need some design advice for on implementing a push notification system. I am using for the backend Symfony 3, Doctrine and postgres as the database. The notification system will have two types of notifications:
1.  Instant notifications
2.  Scheduled Notifications
Instant notifications are when an action is performed in the backend and a notification is instantly pushed. For example, a notification when a user is deleted in the database.

Scheduled notifications is for a notification that has not been triggered yet but will at some known time in the future. The notification will only be triggered when it reaches that set time. For example an Alarm clock.

Based on this I have designed simple tables as follows with some mock data:
[image: Notifications Table]

So with above information the API concept is at user’s device such as mobile phone, it will run a GET/notifications API every 2 mins. The API will return notifications that are before the current date and has not been dismissed for that user. For example, if USER2 executes the GET/notifications with the current date at 18th April 2017 it will return record 3.

My question is this type of design acceptable if not what would be the conventional practice? Also with many users running the same GET API every 2 mins is there a potential to slow down the system? I’m guessing about at most 3000 users.

Finally, as the notifications table grows in records will postgres slow down when performing this API?

Who ever has taken the time to read it all the way through thank you, I am very grateful for any advice.

Comment: Hi, I built the browser push notifications system for realclearpolitics.com If you'd like I can walk you through the process of doing that and all the different technologies that go into it.

Comment: Hi Abraham, yes it would be fantastic if you could walk me through it!

Comment: It's kind of a long process to explain because of all the different details involving this setup. What's an easier way to contact you rather than these comment sections?

Answer (score 2):

**Push Notification.**

If your client devices are asking for notifications via a GET API call, Its not called Push notifications. Down the time, it will be heavy on server side to handle too much unnecessary requests as all users might not have that much notifications.

You shouldn't let your clients call. You should push the notifications to client instead. The `iOS` and `Android` apps can be configured to get push notifications through `deviceId` and `uuid`. Ask your mobile developers for the same. These days even HTML5 browsers are supporting push notifications.

**For storage :**

I think you don't have to store `instant push notifications` in database at all, unless you have an application level requirement to store the logs.

You should only store `scheduled notifications` so that a `Cron job` can pick and push those notifications when they are due.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Jeet this helps alot. To be honest the concept of Push Notifications is completely new to me. So based on what you recommended once the CRON gets the notifications what would be the best way to push it the user? For example do I need to use a service like google messaging or is there a simple way to do it in Syfmony?

Comment: For Push Notification to apps like `Android` or `iOS`. There are certain API from both `Google` And `Apple`. The app build will generate an `appId` which need to be communicated to server after app installation, through which `Google` or `Apple` can deliver the message to respective app. The mobile app developers know that better. I worked on couple of projects, so have a basic idea.

Comment: May I add that this concept becomes more convoluted if you may have more than one service looking for jobs. For example, you keep expanding the notification system and eventually add another `Cron job` to also do some work. Well, now you'll need to worry about preventing duplicate notifications.